# Header not included but symbols get into translation unit anyway

Tags: c++, c++20

This problem has been haunting me for quite a while now. As I am still trying my best to improve my code quality, I have split up my single, massive source file.

The new file structure

[image: file structure]

seemed to produce a weird problem however: symbols from `Windows.h` somehow get into `Framework.hpp`.

The project itself is a simple framework to manage windows for an application. `Framework.hpp` is the header that contains declarations for all the stuff that the framework user is supposed to use. `Internals.hpp`, `Vulkan.hpp` and their associated source files contain declarations and definitions for internal mechanisms. The reason I shaped the file structure that ways was restriction. With that V-shaped gap between the internals and `Framework.hpp`, the user could only interact with all the symbols in `Framework.hpp` and in `Framework.cpp` I could utilise all the internal stuff.

As depicted in [the image above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UhV5.png), `Internals.hpp` includes `Windows.h` (the header for the Win32 API) and `Vulkan.hpp` includes `vulkan.h` (the header for the Vulkan SKD) and wierdly enough, symbols from `Windows.h` end up in `Framework.hpp` and cause naming conflicts.

Like for example:

```
Framework.hpp:293:61: error: macro "CreateWindowA" requires 11 arguments, but only 1 given
  293 |     WND_H CreateWindow(const WindowCreateData& wndCrtData);
```

From my understanding of headers in C / C++ that is not even possible.

I really experimented with this a lot. I tried reproducing this in a more controlled and minimal environment (and even failed at that somehow). The original project was configured and built using Microsoft Visual Studio's toolchain. I have since converted the project to be buildable by CMake using Ninja. The problem persisted. Switched compiler from MSVC to MinGW's g++. The problem persisted.

The only thing that negates this problem is merging all internal source files into `Framework.cpp` (which is the way it was before spliting everything up). I dont even fully understand why that fixes it since no changes to the `#include` directives are made in `Framework.hpp`.

Comment: This is the reason you should use *namespaces* to separate your and your libraries code from other systems and libraries.

Comment: _"... and cause naming conflicts"_ - I suggest that you don't put functions with the same name as WinAPI functions in your global namespace.

Comment: @Some programmer dude The graphic linked in the post contains all `#include` directives except for stuff from the STL

Comment: _"except for stuff from the STL"_ - Tadaa! There you go. Those SL headers may include whatever they like.

Comment: Either do not name your function `CreateWindow` or use parentheses `(CreateWindow)`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `Windows.h` contains macros and since the preprocessor does not care about the namespace that I do have, it still causes problems

Comment: @TedLyngmo They cannot, per the standard.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `Framework.hpp` includes `complex`, `vector` and `string`. Why would `Windows.h` be in there?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Are they only allowed to include whatever other SL headers there are and no platform/implementation specific ones? All implementations I've looked at includes implementation specific headers from the SL headers.

Comment: If you're including stdafx.h then you're probably pulling in pre-compiled-headers

Comment: @ToneXum _"Why"_ - Perhaps it's not  including`Windows.h` but another header that deals with strings or something which in turn includes something that defines the macro.

Comment: @Den-Jason not the case

Comment: @TedLyngmo Only symbols from `Windows.h` get into `Framework.hpp`, nothin else. And even if, that would not be as much of a problem as the windows header.

Comment: You can find out what is included where by adding compiler options, /showIncludes for msvc and -H for other toolchains.

Comment: @TedLyngmo An implementation is not allowed to pollute the global namespace with whatever happens to be in the platform-specific headers. Only names from the C standard library are allowed. Some implementations do have bugs in this area.

Comment: @ToneXum If I understand that diagram correctly, Framework.cpp includes Internals.hpp, which includes Windows.h. Is Internals.hpp included before Framework.hpp, in Framework.cpp? If so, then that would explain it.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/YW41a6eGG). No `Windows.h` is included, no conflict results.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Nice! I did the same and did a `grep` in all of them to see if `CreateWindow` was mentioned in any of them, but it was not.

Comment: @ToneXum Is that the complete error message btw? Doesn't it mention `Framwork.cpp` above it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo there where about 200 error for naming conflicts. I did not want to include them all here since I only needed one to demostrate the point.

Comment: @ToneXum Ok, but is it the complete error message related to the conflict you mention in the question? It doesn't mention `Framework.cpp` just above it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The error originated from `Framework.hpp`

Comment: *"The graphic linked in the post contains all #include directives except for stuff from the STL"* -- The graphic does not show us the order of inclusion, which matters when compiling `Framework.cpp`.

Comment: @ToneXum _" The error originated from `Framework.hpp`"_ - That's not what I was asking about, but ok.

Comment: *"I tried reproducing this a more controlled and minimal environment"* -- Building up is one way to create a [mre]. Tearing down is another. In this case, start with the source file being compiled when the error occurs. Pick the first error. Remove everything from the source file that is not needed to reproduce the error (probably everything but the `#include` lines). Then work on trimming down the headers similarly. If you get stuck, remove about half the code and see if that removed the error (a binary search for the problem).

Comment: To prevent WinAPi macro `CreateWindow` from inflicting your code, you can use this trick: `#define MYPROJECT_PREVENT_MACRO` and use it like this `WND_H CreateWindow MYPROJECT_PREVENT_MACRO(const WindowCreateData& wndCrtData);`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> You can find out what is included where by adding compiler options, /showIncludes for msvc and -H for other toolchains.

Commented by @n. m. could be an AI

Using that information I actually found the cause of the problem.

```
// Vulkan.hpp
#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
#include "vulkan/vulkan.h"
```

Turns out, when defining `VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR` in order to use some Win32 exclusive features, Vulkan just pulls this weird trick to include not only `vulkan.h` but also `windows.h` in every single file.

And yes, `Framework.hpp` was not excluded from this.

I am terribly sorry for opening a question just to figure it out that quickly. To my defense however: I got incredibly frustrated while trying to solve it myself. This problem has actually plagued my progress for 2 whole weeks now.

EDIT: I did some more research and found something called transitive inclusion. I'm not sure if this is the right term for it but if I'm correct then this is what caused the problem.

Comment: *"And yes, `Framework.hpp` was not excluded from this."* -- According to the image in the question, `Framework.hpp` does not include `Vulkan.hpp`, so either this answer is incomplete or the question presents incomplete information.

Comment: @JaMiT It does not (explicitly). Accorfing to g++ `Framework.hpp` includes `Internals.hpp` somehow which itself includes `Vulkan.hpp`.

Comment: *"Accorfing to g++ `Framework.hpp` includes `Internals.hpp`"* -- According to the question, it does not. So this answer is invalid given the information in the question. (This demonstrates why a [mre] is required for debugging help. A **reproducible** example ensures that all relevant details are included.)